NetSuite Master BOL Template Advanced Pdf Question
I am kinda new to NetSuite Advanced PDF templates. I am having a issue modifying dynamic table values in the Master BOL template.
There is a table named X  and it just has headers and  one row identified as
`<tr id="Y_TABLE_PLACEHOLDER"></tr>`

Steps Taken :
I wanted to overwrite the values this place holder generates but I can seem to find it anywhere on the pdf template. -Fail 1
I have also removed this row / line and just used a loop ex:
<#list record.item as item> <tr> <td>${item.tranid}</td> </tr> </#list>
Unfortunately, using this method does not generate any data which means I'm most likely doing something wrong.
What would be a good starting point for me to get this resolved? I have read a ton of NS documentation regarding PDF templates but there's nothing in real detail or directly related to completely modifying a Master BOL template.
Thank you.

If you post the rest of the template, or at least the context around the section you did post, it will make it easier to help.  Also post the results you're getting and a modified version showing your desired end results (or detailed description of what you want to see).
